# Problem with presidents dataset unable to remove n/a values

Tags: r, time-series

```
#presidents is a inbuilt data set in r for time series analysis


data("presidents")
 #checking n/a values

colSums(is.na(presidents))

Output 1:
Error in colSums(is.na(presidents)) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
  checking for data(What is Qtr1,2,3,4(I know it's quarter but is that a label)
```

presidents

```
 Output:
         Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
    1945   NA   87   82   75
    1946   63   50   43   32
    1947   35   60   54   55
    1948   36   39   NA   NA
    1949   69   57   57   51
    1950   45   37   46   39
    1951   36   24   32   23
    1952   25   32   NA   32
    1953   59   74   75   60
    1954   71   61   71   57
    1955   71   68   79   73
    1956   76   71   67   75
    1957   79   62   63   57
    1958   60   49   48   52
    1959   57   62   61   66
    1960   71   62   61   57
    1961   72   83   71   78
    1962   79   71   62   74
    1963   76   64   62   57
    1964   80   73   69   69
    1965   71   64   69   62
    1966   63   46   56   44
    1967   44   52   38   46
    1968   36   49   35   44
    1969   59   65   65   56
    1970   66   53   61   52
    1971   51   48   54   49
    1972   49   61   NA   NA          #NA values are there in it.
    1973   68   44   40   27
    1974   28   25   24   24
```

Comment: I tried the split function but it does not split() into four columns it just shows your data in split format

Comment: What is your ultimate aim? What do you want to do with the NAs?

Comment: Well, if you run `colnames(presidents)`, you should get `NULL` as a results. Then if you do a `class(presidents)`, you'll see that you're not dealing with a df or a Matrix. Finally, if you run a `View(presidents)`, you'll see you have a vector, not a nice, square df. How about first converting your data to dataframe ? `df <- data.frame(Y=as.matrix(presidents), date=time(presidents))`

Comment: `is.na(presidents)` gives you a vector of booleans, with `TRUE` where the original value is `NA`?! But even with `!is.na(presidents)` I'm sure how you would use `colSums` on that? `presidents[!is.na(presidents)]` would remove the `NA` values...

Comment: The presidents data is a single time-series. In fact, you cannot remove the NA and keep the structure of the data intact. You can impute the missing values, but not remove them physically. You can also calculate the overall mean, with missing values omitted. But I strongly suggest you read @NelsonGon's question again and answer it. :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, first you'd like to count the number of NA per quarter. To do this, you have to convert your object to a format you can manipulate more easily. After a few research, here's what you can do to get your data in the desired format :

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

# Load the dataset
data("presidents")
class(presidents)

# Convert your ts data
df <- data.frame(Y=as.matrix(presidents), date=time(presidents))

# Get your data in a more familiar format
df <- df %>%
  mutate(yearmon = as.yearmon(date)) %>%
  mutate(year = year(yearmon)) %>%
  mutate(quarter = paste0("Q", quarter(yearmon))) %>%
  select(c(year, quarter, Y)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = quarter, values_from = Y) 

#Edit : remove the last row if you want your data in a long format
```

Once this is done, you can go back to do your

```
colSums(is.na(df))
```

Finally, you can remove all rows containing NAs with

```
df_nona <- df %>%
  drop_na()
```

Please be careful though, as the others mentioned in the comments, always ask yourself why you think you should remove your NAs. If you want to calculate a mean, you can always `na.rm=T` should you need to. Otherwise, you can also drop those observations if you want to but then you'll need your data in a long format (see comment in code above)